# Unit testing mocking interactions

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking

I'm trying to implement unit testing for a large enterprise app that has multiple layers and interactions between classes.
Reading about this type of test, I see that it is not recommended to verify interaction, you should test "observable results". For example:

```
public void Purchase_succeeds_when_enough_inventory(){
   var storeMock = new Mock<IStore>();

   storeMock.Setup(x => x.HasEnoughInventory(Product.Shampoo, 5)).Returns(true);
   
   var customer = new Customer();
   bool success = customer.Purchase(storeMock.Object, Product.Shampoo, 5);
   
   Assert.True(success);
   storeMock.Verify(x => x.RemoveInventory(Product.Shampoo, 5),Times.Once);
}
```

In this case, verifying that RemoveInventory is called it's wrong (according to the theory), because it is an implementation detail.
Now, how should I test that the product has been removed from the inventory, given that the database or dao classes are mocked? There's no way to know, other than check that the function that does remove the product is called and hope for the best.

What am I missing here? Should I implement this in a different manner?

Comment: Add the program language tag

Comment: Theres nothing wrong with what you're doing here. There is no observable behavior to test. What theory is this? Can you add a link to a description ?

Comment: Ok, well the book is Unit Testing: Principles, Practices and Patterns from Vladimir Khorikov. And it basically says that you should not assert interactions among collaborators